# Does Seeker's Biting Swarm give both a dex bonus and wis bonus to damage?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Biting Swarm damage is calculated at 1[W]+Wis. If you are using an xbow would that be 1[1d10+Dex]+Wis?

Answer (score 9):

No. [W] refers to the weapon's damage die alone - i.e. 1d10 in this case. That power only deals *1d10 + Wis* in damage.

Note that the *Basic Ranged Attack*'s damage line is *[W] + Dex*. Your dex bonus is added as part of the Basic Ranged Attack, not as part of your weapon's damage die.